# tail wheel landing roll out

Tags: flight-training

I'm new to tail wheel and recently every time in my landing roll out the plane seems to have a tendency to to go to the right and when i try to correct it feels like the plane will tip over. Is there a reason for this? is there a way to overcome it? I am Flying a C-170B by the way with an Alaskan bush wheel tail wheel and standard tires

Comment: Welcome to the site. Are you doing three point or wheeler landings? Also, when does it go to the right, give more detail on your technique and when exactly it's going wrong.

Comment: By tip over you mean tip up on its nose, or drop a wing tip toward the ground?